# Ffmpeg segment doesn't show file size update in real time

Tags: node.js, unix, ffmpeg, segment, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to run ffmpeg mp3 stream with segmentation for each hour. Everything is working perfectly, except for one thing: when i run the command, the file size doesn't grow in real-time as i need, it only grows in packages of 256k.

Is there a way to turn a "real-time mode"?

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with ffmpeg 3.4.6

This is the code i'm trying to run on linux terminal: 
`ffmpeg -i http://radiocentova.conectastm.com:8363/stream -y -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 16k -ac 1 -ar 11025 -vn -strftime 1 -f segment -segment_time 3600 -flush_packets 1 @test_%Y%m%d%H%M%S+00.mp3`

Recording with segment:
[image: Recording with segment]
Recording without segment:
[image: Recording without segment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flush packets option has to be directed to the child muxer (mp3 in this case), so

`-segment_format_options flush_packets=1` instead of `-flush_packets 1`.